# Moving a file to a subdirectory with renaming with time stamp in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to copy a file to a subdirectory with its name changed to `name_timestamp`(by appending the time stamp).

I'm using a COPY `method` on a csv file and once that copy is done, I need to move the CSV file to a subdirectory and rename it to `CSV_timestamp`.

Below is the sample code. Can anyone help me or suggest me on how to do this?

```
 import os, shutil, time

 if not os.path.exists(dirName):
    os.mkdir(dirName)
    print("Directory " , dirName ,  " Created ")
 else:    
    print("Directory " , dirName ,  " already exists")

def copyFile(src, dest):
    try:
        shutil.copy(src, dest)
    # eg. src and dest are the same file
    except shutil.Error as e:
        print('Error: %s' % e)
    # eg. source or destination doesn't exist
    except IOError as e:
        print('Error: %s' % e.strerror)

os.rename("path/to/current/age.csv", "path/to/new/destination/for/age.csv")
shutil.move("path/to/current/age.csv", "path/to/new/destination/for/age.csv")
```

Comment: Your script is working so far and you're asking how to add the timestamp to the file name?

Comment: I don't see how it is working. The indentation is incorrect. `os.rename` moves the file and then `shutil.move` tries to move it again even though it's gone and the `copyFile` function is never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sticking to your approach (with a function that checks whether the directory exists etc.), you could do the following:

```
import os
import shutil
from time import gmtime, strftime

def copyFile(old_path, new_directory):
   # check if the directory already exists
    if not os.path.exists(new_directory):
        os.mkdir(new_directory)
        print(f"Directory {new_directory} Created.")
    else:    
        print(f"Directory {new_directory} already exists.")

    # create new path from new_directory, the filename and the timestamp
    new_path = new_directory + old_path.split("/")[len(old_path)-1].split(".")[0] + strftime("%Y_%m_%d", gmtime()) + ".csv"

    # copy the file to the new path
    try:
        shutil.copy(old_path, new_path)
    # eg. src and dest are the same file
    except shutil.Error as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
    # eg. source or destination doesn't exist
    except IOError as e:
        print(f"Error: {e.strerror}")

old_path = '/path/to/directory/file.csv'
new_directory = '/path/to/new/directory/'

copyFile(old_path, new_directory)
```

Please note that

1. As of Python 3.6, you can use f-strings to include variables in strings more easily.
2. It wasn't clear to me what kind of timestamp you are looking for.
   This approach will give you a stamp in the format of `YYYY_MM_DD`
   of the current day, but you could easily change that, see the
   [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime) on the `time` package.
3. After using `shutil.copy`, you don't need `shutil.move` any more, as
   the first already copied your file and saved it to the destination
   path.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as setting your destination path to whatever directory you want it in when you finish.

For example, say your file is in users/foo/bar/myfile.csv (this would be your `src` path). Suppose you want that file's copy in users/mydocuments/bar/foo/mynewfile.csv (this would be your `dest` path).

All you'd need to do is:

```
import shutil
import os
src = 'users/foo/bar/myfile.csv'
tstamp = os.path.getmtime(path)
dest = 'users/mydocuments/bar/foo/mynewfile' + tstamp + '.csv'
shutil.move(src,dest)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use os.rename() insteed

```
import time
timestamp_name=int(time.time())
os.rename('path/to/file/name.text','path/to/file/'+timestamp_name+'.txt)
```

Comment: `os.rename` will take the file and move it. However, the author of the question needs to copy a file.